# Take string from UITextField and use it as a double

Tags: objective-c, string, double

I'm trying to make a unit converter as my first app. I've been having trouble getting the numeric value from the textfield, so I can multiply it by whatever constant to convert the units. Also, how can I add a decimal place to a numeric key pad?

Comment: And your language is?

Comment: When asking for help, it really helps to indicate what language you are using as that will greatly influence the answer.

Comment: Please don't put multiple questions in one thread.

Comment: I'm using objective c, sorry about that

Answer (score 4):

Use the NSString doubleValue property to convert the string value from the UITextBox into a double.

```
double d = [str doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float value = [self.myTextField.text floatValue];
```